# How to upgrade Debian 9 (EOL) to Debian 10

Tags: debian

I have to confess that I missed upgrading Debian 9 to 10 on a virtual development machine. Now Debian 9 is EOL.

All I get are 404 or 403 errors when I try to fetch the necessary upgrade packages because support for Debian 9 ended on June 2022.

> Err:10 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch Release   403  Forbidden

or

> Err:7 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch Release
> 403  Forbidden

So far, I did the well-known routines for upgrading:

1. replace every instance of "stretch" with "buster" inside /etc/apt/sources.list
2. sudo apt update # that's where the trouble started
3. sudo apt upgrade
4. sudo apt full-upgrade

What can I do now to upgrade to 10 (or even 11 if necessary)? Do I have to get the packages or upgrade information from a third party? Is there any possible solution at all?

Here is the output of *sudo apt update*

```
juergen@masch1:~$ sudo apt update  
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease  
Hit:2 http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie InRelease  
Get:3 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]  
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [34.8 kB]  
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x stretch InRelease  
Get:6 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [56.6 kB]  
Ign:7 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease  
Err:8 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch Release  
  403  Forbidden  
Get:9 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main Sources [255 kB]  
Get:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main 
amd64 Packages [347 kB]  
Get:11 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main  Translation-en [188 kB]  
Get:12 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster/main Sources [7843 kB]  
Get:13 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7911 kB]  
Ign:14 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository buster InRelease  
Err:15 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository buster Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 104.207.151.13 80]  
Get:16 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-en [5969 kB]  
Get:17 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-de [1654 kB]  
Get:18 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster/main Translation-de_DE [830 B]  
Get:19 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Sources [4616 B]  
Get:20 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main amd64 Packages [8788 B]  
Get:21 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian buster-updates/main Translation-en [6915 B]  
Reading package lists... Done  
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php stretch Release' does no longer have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: The repository 'http://download.webmin.com/download/repository buster Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors shown by `apt update` only concern third-party repositories. You should at least:

- check whether they provide support for Debian 10
- update the repository descriptions in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` to reference `buster` rather than `stretch`

As it is, you have the updated repository indexes for Debian 10, so you should be able to upgrade (at least, see what `apt upgrade` determines — it will tell you what it wants to do and give you the opportunity to stop before it actually does it). You may however run into issues with third-party packages, and in some cases you’ll have to remove the affected third-party packages in order to successfully upgrade to Debian 10.